# Database Queries in One Spark Worker Thread

Tags: database, apache-spark, bigdata

Recently I've started learning Spark to accelerate the processing. In my situation the input RDD of the Spark application does not contain all the data required for the batch processing. As a result, I have to do some SQL queries in each worker thread.

Preprocessing of all the input data is possible, but it takes too long.

I know the following questions may be too "general", but any experience will help.

1. is it possible to do some SQL queries in worker threads?
2. will the scheduling on the data server be the bottle neck, if a single query is complicated?
3. which database suits this situation (with good concurrency abilities maybe)? MongoDB? *SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to answer some of your questions without a specific use-case. But the following generic answers might be of some help

1. Yes. You can access external data sources (RDBMS, Mongo etc.). You can use `mapPartitions` to even improve performance by creating the connections once. See an [example here](https://bzhangusc.wordpress.com/2014/06/19/optimize-map-performamce-with-mappartitions/)
2. can't answer without looking at specific example
3. Database selection is dependent on use-cases.

Comment: Thanks for your help! To 2. and 3., yeah, maybe I should first try  those possibilities out. To 1. thanks for the information about `mapPartitions`, it really helpful!